# Custom links in file structure TexStudio

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, texstudio, xparse

I'm using `xparse` to customize `\section` command. And now I'd like to have an additional word added in TeXstudio file scructure.

Here my modified `\section` command:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{smmo}
{
\hspace{-4.7ex}
\textbf{\Large{#2.}\,\large{#3}}
\;#4
\vspace{1ex}
}
```

Such input `\section*{1.1}{2041}[Text here]` will give the following result:
[image]

Here is what I can see in file structure

[image]

But I'd like to see there `Exercise 1.1`

Comment: note size commands do not take an argument `\Large{#2.}` should be `{\Large#2.}` if you mean to restrict the Large font to `#2` but why are you not using the latex heading definitions? This definition loses most of the features of a heading, notably it will allow page break immediately after the heading before the section text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I just need this to have an ability to click and immediately jump to it in the editor.

Comment: also how have you defined `\;` (the default definition would give an error there)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, works perfectly for me.

Comment: It is not surprising that it works for you as you will have defined it somewhere. It doesn't work for anyone else. That is why examples should always be complete small documents that show the issue and allow answers to be tested.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, here you are:
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{smmo}
{
 \hspace{-4.7ex}
 \textbf{{\Large#2.}\,\large{#3}}
 \;#4
 \vspace{1ex}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{1.1}{2041}[Text here]

\end{document}`

Comment: ah yes `amsmath` (I could perhaps have guessed that but we shouldn't have to guess:-)